What is radius of the circle tangent to $y=x^2+1$ at the point $(1,2)$ with the same second derivative?

A circle is tangent to the parabola $y=x^2+1$ at the point $(1,2)$. If
the second-order derivatives of the circle and the parabola with respect to $x$
at the point $(1,2)$ are equal, find the radius of the
circle.

Here is my work:
For the parabola, $y''=2$ so the second order derivative for the circle at the point $(1,2)$ should be equal to $2$. Let the equation of the circle be $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$. Taking the derivative with respect to $x$:
$$(x-a)+y'(y-b)=0 \quad\Rightarrow \quad y'=-\dfrac{x-a}{y-b}$$
Substituting $x=1$, and $y=2$ in the above equation gives $y'=-\dfrac{1-a}{2-b}$. Now, taking the second order derivative,
$$1+y''y+y'^2-by''=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad y''=-\dfrac{1+y'^2}{y-b}$$
Substituting $y'=-\dfrac{1-a}{2-b}$ and $y=2$, gives,
$$y''=-\dfrac{1+(\dfrac{1-a}{2-b})^2}{2-b}$$
I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

As it's a tangent, you also know that $y'=2$ so you can eliminate $a$ or $b$ before taking the second derivative.

@Ramashalanka Thanks a lot. Using your hint I could solve the question and I got $r=\dfrac{5\sqrt5}2$

You should end up getting the same thing as the "osculating circle" if you want to look that up, e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Glad you finished the problem with the hint. You can in fact continue your solution (CW-ing this solution to get it off the unanswered list).
You have found out the following information. From the parabola, $y'=2$ and hence $$-2=\frac{1-a}{2-b}$$ You also found out that $$y''=-\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{1-a}{2-b}\right)^2}{2-b}$$ You can simplify this using the fact that $(1,2)$ is a point on the circle, and get $$r^2=2(b-2)^3$$
Now we use the fact that $(1,2)$ is a point on the circle again, this time in the equation of the circle itself.
$$(1-a)^2+(2-b)^2=r^2=2(b-2)^3\Rightarrow \left(\frac{1-a}{2-b}\right)^2+1=2(b-2)\Rightarrow b=9/2$$
This also gives $a=-4$ and $r=\frac{5\sqrt5}{2}$ and you are done.

Thanks for the answer. Actually, I found it easier to take derivative of both sides of the equation of the circle and do it another time to make $y''$ to appear, and then proceed with substituting. But anyway, it doesn't matter.

@user1380196 Yes that is indeed more convenient. I just wanted to say that the way you were doing it can also be finished easily.

$a=4$ may not be satisfying the equations.

@BobDobbs It was a typo. Fixed

For the parabola, we have:
$$f(x) = x^2+1 \implies f(1) = 2$$
$$f'(x) = 2x \implies f'(1) = 2$$
$$f''(x) = 2 \implies f''(1) = 2$$

Recall that the equation of a circle centered at $(a, b)$ is:
$$(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$$
Implicit differentiation gives:
$$2(x - a) ~dx + 2(y - b) ~dy = 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x - a}{y - b}$$
Using the quotient rule $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \frac{u'(x)v(x) - u(x)v'(x)}{v(x)^2}$, with $u(x) = a - x$ and $v(x) = y - b$, gives the second derivative:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{(-1)(y - b) - (a - x)\frac{dy}{dx}}{(y - b)^2}$$
$$ = \frac{-y + b + (x - a)(-\frac{x - a}{y - b})}{(y - b)^2}$$
$$ = -\frac{(y - b)^2 + (x - a)^2}{(y - b)^3}$$

To solve for $a$, $b$, and $r$, we know:
(1) The point $(x = 1, y = 2)$ is on the circle.
$$(1 - a)^2 + (2 - b)^2 = r^2$$
$$1 - 2a + a^2 + 4 - 4b + b^2 = r^2$$
$$5 - 2a + a^2 - 4b + b^2 = r^2$$
(2) The circle shares a tangent line with the parabola at $(x = 1, y = 2)$, so has the same first derivative at that point.
$$2 = -\frac{1 - a}{2 - b}$$
Solving for $a$ gives $a = 5 - 2b$.
(3) The two curves also have the same second derivative at that point.
$$2 = -\frac{(2 - b)^2 + (1 - a)^2}{(2 - b)^3}$$
Or, after some algebraic rearranging:
$$2b^3 - 13b^2 + 28b - a^2 + 2a - 21 = 0$$
Substituting $a = 5 - 2b$ from (2) gives:
$$2b^3 - 17b^2 + 44b - 36 = 0$$
With the help of the Rational Root Theorem, this factors into:
$$2(b - 2)^2(b - \frac{9}{2})$$
And thus, either $b = 2$ (and $a = 1$), or $b = \frac{9}{2}$ (and $a = -4$).
Substituting into (1) gives:
$$a = -4, b = \frac{9}{2} \implies r^2 = \frac{125}{4}$$
$$a = 1, b = 2 \implies r^2 = 0$$
But a circle with a radius of zero isn't really a “circle”, just a point.  So let's reject this solution and use the other one, giving the circle equation:
$$\boxed{(x + 4)^2 + (y - \frac{9}{2})^2 = \frac{125}{4}}$$
From which $\boxed{r = \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2}} \approx 5.59017$.
